# Row to string with space between items

Tags: vba, excel

I have this:

```
| col1 | col2 | col 3 |
|    5 |   FA |   OFF |
|  107 |   FA |    ON |
|   96 |   FO |    ON |
```

and I want to MsgBox each row like that

```
Dim str As String
Dim r As Long

r = 2
While Celles(r,1).Value <> ""
    str = Rows(r)                    ' don't know how get row with space between items
    MsgBox str
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("""C:\mypath\prog.exe"" " & str)

    r = r+1
Wend
```

I want 3 MsgBox to appear  `5 FA OFF` `107 FA ON` `96 FO ON`.

Therefore, how to get a row properly and add space between items ?

(After i want to call `WshShellExec` with parameters)

Comment: What is the desired output? I could not find a question to answer.

Comment: How to get an entire row into a string ? :)

Comment: Look at `join` and `transpose` excel ranges .value returns are arrays in VBA. `join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("a1:c1").Value)),"|")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub x()

For i = 1 To 3
a = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("a1:c1").Offset(i, 0).Value))
Debug.Print Join(a, "|")
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below to combine the `String`s per row:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombStringinRow()

Dim str As String
Dim r As Long, Col As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data from column "A"

For r = 2 To LastRow
    LastCol = Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get last column in current row

    For Col = 1 To LastCol
        If str <> "" Then
            str = str & " " & Cells(r, Col)
        Else
            str = Cells(r, Col)
        End If
    Next Col

    MsgBox str
    str = ""
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

just build str from values in all columns

```
Dim i as Long 'HERE EDITED
For i = 0 To 2
str = str & " " & Cells(r, 1).Offset(,i) 'HERE EDITED
Next i
MsgBox str
str = ""
```

Comment: This won't work. You don't reference `i` anywhere in your code

Comment: it will if Option Explicit is not present.

Comment: You've just opened Pandora's box

Comment: Also, what I meant was you use `i` in your loop and `Cells(r,1)` in your code, you aren't increasing the column counter (which I assume you're trying to do) so you'll never get columns 2 or 3. Also, `Cells(r,0)` will also return an error

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try...

```
Sub ConcatenateRowValues()
Dim x
Dim i As Long
Dim Str As String
x = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    Str = Join(Application.Index(x, i, 0), " ")
    MsgBox Str
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go

```
Sub example()
    Dim str As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c

    ' I'd recommend changing this to your actual sheet
    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            str = vbNullString
            For Each c In Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
                str = str & " " & c.Value2
            Next c
            MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Trim(str)
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ShaiRado I remove it with the `Trim` at the end. I use `WorkSheetFunction.Trim` as opposed to `Trim` as it removes additional spaces between words as well avoiding the scenario of having a blank cell in the middle to produce 3 spaces when there should only be one